# How to find the nearest row based on two integer columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Here is a MySQL table, which has three rows.

```
ram cpu
  1   2
  4   8
  8  16
```

if I give input as ram=7 and cpu=9,

the query has to smartly select the closest row based on the two input values and return me a single row.

example result which I expect for 7,9 combination:

```
ram cpu
4    8
```

is this possible to achieve?

Consider me having thousands of combinations like this. I need a query that always smartly returns a single row.

Comment: Hello. You should specify do you mean by the closest. Is it the row with minimal (abs(ram-given_ram) + abs(cpu - given_cpu))?

Comment: Same weight? (Or is CPU more or less important than RAM?)

Comment: The row contains which is Closest of these two inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You never gave us an exact heuristic for what "closest" means, given that there are two columns involved.  Assuming you can accept the record whose sum of absolute difference from the two input values in smallest, then here is one way:

```
SELECT ram, cpu
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ABS(ram - 7) + ABS(cpu - 9)
LIMIT 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: @Strawberry Well, pi contains the digit 8, so that's definitely one source!

Comment: From input box in my web app